# how to get api from toggle button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a toggle button, that I put the code below:

```
  Widget buildHeader({
    required Widget child,
    required String text,
  }) =>
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 3),
          child,
        ],
      );

  Widget buildSwitch() => Transform.scale(
        scale: 2,
        child: Switch.adaptive(
          activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          activeTrackColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),
          splashRadius: 50,
          value: value,
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.value = value),
        ),
      );
```

and `value` variable is : `bool value = true;`

This works fine but I want this api `/api/v1/main/enable/{userId}` to run when the toggle is on

and this api `/api/v1/main/disable/{userId}` to run when the toggle is off, How can I do this?

These two api are `PUT` and i already write a code for the GET api, and it works fine, but I do not know how to use the toggle for these two PUT api

i code like below for get and it work well

```
    print('bye');
    String token = await getToken();
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('/api/v1/main/active/get'),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('ok');
    } else {
      print("no");
    }
  }
```

Comment: You simply have to call you API method on the `onChanged` part with the value as parameter

Comment: @FPerroch how i can do that? can you give a example in A/Q ?
don't comment please

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your API method and change the value if it succeeds :

```
Widget buildSwitch() => Transform.scale(
    scale: 2,
    child: Switch.adaptive(
      activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      activeTrackColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),
      splashRadius: 50,
      value: value,
      onChanged: (value) async {
        await apiCallMethod().then((success) {
          if (success) {
            setState(() => this.value = value);
          }
        });
      }
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class ApiHelper{

  static String baseUrl = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20";

  static Future<List<dynamic>> getUserList(String endPoint) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl+endPoint));
    return jsonDecode(response.body)['results'];

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package [api_toggle](https://pub.dev/packages/api_toggle) to help not to call the API multiple times when repeatedly clicking